# Date value as float - Apple's iWork Numbers 09 - internal XML

Tags: date, datetime, date-format, iwork

I am writing a script in PHP which will convert Numbers file into HTML table, but I can not figure out which format is used for date storage. The date cell tag looks like

```
<sf:d 
    sf:s="SFTCellStyle-128" 
    sf:w="84.074219" 
    sf:h="14" 
    sf:cell-date="371397519.99999952" />
```

so the date must be in sf:cell-date attribute, but I can not figure out how to convert it into human readable format. Any ideas? I have never seen date value as float number.

Comment: And it is not UNIX timestamp with additional precision

Comment: Number of seconds since 01/01/2001 at 00:00:00.

Comment: 371397519.99999952 should be 2012-10-08 13:58

Comment: Yes, hakre is right, please make your comment as an answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in a comment, it is the number of seconds since 01/01/2001 at 00:00:00. Equipped with that knowledge and because this goes hand in hand with the [UNIX Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) all you need to do is to define and use the offset. It should be compatible with nearly every of the existing PHP date functions and objects, for example with [`date`](http://php.net/date):

```
define('CELL_DATE_EPOCH_OFFSET', 978307200);

$sf_cell_date = 371397519.99999952;

echo date('r', CELL_DATE_EPOCH_OFFSET + $sf_cell_date);
```

The output of this little script is (in my timezone):

```
Mon, 08 Oct 2012 15:58:39 +0200
```

I hope this is helpful. *`978307200`* is the unix timestamp for `01/01/2001 00:00:00 UTC`, you can get with PHP for example with the following code-example:

```
$base = new DateTime('01/01/2001 00:00:00 UTC');

echo $base->getTimestamp(), "\n";
```

in case that was your problem.